# Aggregate review is missing on Google SERP

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Recently I've lost my star review on Google SERP. I know that reasons may be differents and various, but I would to be sure that I didn't made mistakes on code:

```html
   <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" style="text-align:right;">
         <b><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> on 
         <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">857</span> reviews</b>
   </div>
```

Could Google have released an update?

Comment: What is the rating for? Restaurant, product etc?

Comment: products such as curtains, roll-up, etc

Comment: Is this on a product overview page or single products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet you provided in the main post: in isolation is not valid according to [Google SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

*The review has no reviewed item specified*

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" style="text-align:right;">
  <b><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> on 
  <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">857</span> reviews</b>
</div>
```

This is fixed by adding in `itemprop="itemreviewed"`

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" style="text-align:right;">
  <h3 itemprop="itemreviewed">Mario Bros service</h3>
  <b><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> of 
  <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">857</span> reviews</b>
</div>
```

---

> Instances of `AggregateRating` may appear as values for the following properties
>
> - Brand
> - CreativeWork
> - Event
> - Offer
> - **Organization**
> - Place
> - **Product**
> - Service
>
> Source - http://schema.org/AggregateRating

---

Your full snippet in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817831/aggregate-review-is-missing-on-google-serp?noredirect=1#comment68987746_40872869) (which I have simplified) is using the Organization schema http://schema.org/Organization and a different vocabulary for Review aggregate

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <body>
    <div class="review">
      <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
        <img itemprop="rating" src="#" alt="173 recensioni" />
        <span itemprop="count">173 recensioni</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which has multiple errors.

---

**The valid way would be:**

Using data-vocabulary.org

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 itemprop="name">Mario Bros</h1>
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
        <h3 itemprop="itemreviewed">Mario Bros service</h3>
        <p>
          <span itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
            <em itemprop="average">5</em> out of <em itemprop="best"> 5 </em>
          </span>
          <b>based on</b>
          <!-- How many people rated this item? -->
          <em itemprop="votes">173</em> ratings.
        </p>
        <p>
          <!-- How many people reviewed this item? -->
          <em itemprop="count">45 </em> user reviews.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Using schema.org

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 itemprop="name">Mario Bros</h1>
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
          <em itemprop="ratingValue">5</em> out of <em itemprop="bestRating">5</em> based on <em itemprop="ratingCount">24</em> user ratings.
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

You also mentioned in comments that they are products:

> products such as curtains, roll-up, etc

This is [Google's example from the Products data type](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products#single-product-page):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <img itemprop="image" src="dell-30in-lcd.jpg" />
  <span itemprop="name">Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor</span>
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">87</span>
    out of <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span>
    based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">24</span> user ratings
  </div>
</div>
```

Modified for your criteria would be:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 itemprop="name">Mario Bros</h1>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <img itemprop="image" src="curtains.jpg" />
          <span itemprop="name">Acme brand Curtains</span>   
          <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <em itemprop="ratingValue">5</em> out of <em itemprop="bestRating">5</em> based on <em itemprop="ratingCount">173</em> reviews.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Enchanced further:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 itemprop="name">Mario Bros</h1>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <span itemprop="brand">Acme brand</span>
          <img itemprop="image" src="curtains.jpg" />
          <span itemprop="name">Acme brand Curtains</span>   
          <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <em itemprop="ratingValue">5</em> out of <em itemprop="bestRating">5</em> based on <em itemprop="ratingCount">173</em> reviews.
          </div>
          <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <!--price is 1000, a number, with locale-specific thousands separator and decimal mark, and the € character is marked up with the machine-readable code "EUR" -->
            <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">€</span>
            <span itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
            <span>In stock</span>
          </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggest. My AggregateReview is a part of "Organization".
<html  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"  dir="ltr" lang="it">..etc...

Comment: @mariobros Is this code you are writing, or is it being generated?

Comment: it's the same for category pages?

Comment: @mariobros for the product listings, yes.